# Chat with only javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying to make a chat in a long time, but I had no succes in making it.

I tried alot of ways, but making it insert the msg to my database and then with javascript refresh the chat every second, and get the msg from database, but that dosent work that well.

I was wondering is theire a way to make a chat with only javascript?
So it appends to a div all the users can see.

I saw some sites do this but I haven't been able to do it myself.

Comment: there will aways be a server involved - so "chat with only javascript" (meaning client-side js): No. Of course if your server runs Node.js it would still be js - but on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - You can make a chat client that takes advantage of Websockets.

The only thing required is that you run a server in order to forward requests to other clients as they arrive.

The server can be written in a variety of different languages -- some of the most popular are  C/C++ (Qt),   node.js,  Python,  and go.

There are more languages which can provide this as ability as well ---

This came from http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/websocket-chat-client

```js
var output;

var websocket;

function WebSocketSupport() {
  if (browserSupportsWebSockets() === false) {
    document.getElementById("ws_support").innerHTML = "<h2>Sorry! Your web browser does not supports web sockets</h2>";

    var element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

    return;
  }

  output = document.getElementById("chatbox");

  websocket = new WebSocket('ws:localhost:999');

  websocket.onopen = function(e) {
    writeToScreen("You have have successfully connected to the server");
  };


  websocket.onmessage = function(e) {
    onMessage(e)
  };

  websocket.onerror = function(e) {
    onError(e)
  };
}

function onMessage(e) {
  writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;"> ' + e.data + '</span>');
}

function onError(e) {
  writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + e.data);
}

function doSend(message) {
  var validationMsg = userInputSupplied();
  if (validationMsg !== '') {
    alert(validationMsg);
    return;
  }
  var chatname = document.getElementById('chatname').value;

  document.getElementById('msg').value = "";

  document.getElementById('msg').focus();

  var msg = '@<b>' + chatname + '</b>: ' + message;

  websocket.send(msg);

  writeToScreen(msg);
}

function writeToScreen(message) {
  var pre = document.createElement("p");
  pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
  pre.innerHTML = message;
  output.appendChild(pre);
}

function userInputSupplied() {
  var chatname = document.getElementById('chatname').value;
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg').value;
  if (chatname === '') {
    return 'Please enter your username';
  } else if (msg === '') {
    return 'Please the message to send';
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

function browserSupportsWebSockets() {
  if ("WebSocket" in window) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px arial;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px;
}
#controls,
p,
span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input {
  font: 12px arial;
}
a {
  color: #0000FF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#wrapper,
#loginform {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  background: #66CCFF;
  width: 504px;
  border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
}
#chatbox {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 270px;
  width: 430px;
  border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#chatname {
  width: 395px;
  border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
  margin-left: 25px;
  float: left;
}
#msg {
  width: 395px;
  border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
}
#submit {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>WebSocket PHP Open Group Chat App</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="websocket_client.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="javascript:WebSocketSupport()">
  <div id="ws_support"></div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
      <h3 class="welcome">Welcome to WebSocket PHP Open Group Chat App v1</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="chatbox"></div>

    <div id="controls">
      <label for="name"><b>Name</b>
      </label>
      <input name="chatname" type="text" id="chatname" size="67" placeholder="Type your name here" />
      <input name="msg" type="text" id="msg" size="63" placeholder="Type your message here" />
      <input name="sendmsg" type="submit" id="sendmsg" value="Send" onclick="doSend(document.getElementById('msg').value)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```